# Can openssl's S/MIME handle RSASSA-PSS

Tags: openssl

I need to sign emails with S/MIME and want to do this using `openssl`. The requested signature algorithm is RSASSA-PSS. I couldn't figure out how to specify the signature algorithm to `openssl smime`. What I've figured out already is:

```
openssl smime -sign -in unsigned.msg -out signed.msg -signer private.pem -md sha512
```

However, the algorithm used following this command is `RSA`. Does anyone have an idea how to switch this to `RSASSA-PSS`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use openssl cms to do that:

```
openssl cms -in msg.txt -sign -inkey key.pem -signer cert.pem \
    -keyopt rsa_padding_mode:pss -md sha512 -out msg.eml
```

Comment: Awesome, this works. I didn't know about `openssl cms`